# How long can you keep pancake batter in the refrigerator?

Tags: pancakes

How long can you keep pancake batter in the refrigerator ?

Comment: Welcome! I've marked your question as a duplicate of an already-answered one, but if the answers there don't cover your situation, feel free to clarify here and we can reopen it to get you answers!

Comment: fwiw, i don't like the consistency of hour-old batter and i can't imagine they cook well with cold batter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but this is for home, pancakes freeze very well. I will always make a double batch on weekends and cook them all. Those that are not eaten will be bagged in a zip-top bag and stored in the freezer. When you want to reheat them, place up to three frozen pancakes on a plate and microwave for one minute each. Flip them and microwave in 1 minute increments until no longer cold in the middle.

I worry that the leavening agents in uncooked batter will not maintain activity for very long in a refrigerator